# Keep two WPF userControl ratio when hosted in Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, desktop-application

I have 2 WPF UserControl (`userControl1`, `userControl2`). In my winform I placed 2 elementHost the first one is set to `userControl1` and the second to `userControl2`.

The first elementHost has the property Dock to `left`, the second is set to `fill`.

At runtime when I resize the winform only the second elementHost is resized. I'd like keep the same ratio between the two elementHost.

How can I solve this problem ? I talk about a better solution than make the calculation on the height of both elementHost in the Winform `OnSizeChanged`

Thanks,

Comment: Try docking both of the user control as Fill, if that does not work then i would suggest to have a single element host and have WPF manage the resizing which is a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option you could place them in a `WPF` user control with a `Grid` of two columns and set the `Width` of the column to * for proportional sizing.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" " >         
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter  Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" />
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Column=0 />
    <local:UserControl2 Grid.Column=1 />
</Grid>
```